# Phonegap android don't kill by os

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, foreground

Hi everyone ( my apologies if this question it's already answered but nothing work for me).

I'm developping an android APP with phonegap 3.1 and i need to watch the position of the user and send this in a server. All the comunication it's done with javascript.

For the moment, my app work fine but when it go in background android kill my app randomly. I need something for my app stay in background.

I know i can use a background service but i don't know if i can execute my javascript function with a background service.

An other isue i can read it's to make an notification and lunch a startForeground() but in witch service i can lunch this startForeground(). For the moment i tryed this :

```
    mNotificationManager.notify(tag.hashCode(), noti);
    Service s = (Service) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(ns);
    s.startForeground(777, noti);
```

and i also try this :

```
    context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Notification noti = StatusNotificationIntent.buildNotification(context, tag, contentTitle, contentText, flag);
    mNotificationManager.notify(tag.hashCode(), noti);
    ((Service) context).startForeground(777, noti);
```

But i know it's the wrong way to do this.

Thx for your futur answers.

Comment: Not so sure about javascript and services, but you are right you need a service for background operations.

Comment: I also tryed to make a partial wakelock but it's doesn't work too ...